# error: incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android

I got an error on my `Adapter`, this is my code, the error is pointed on this code, its on `HomeFragment.java`, its says:

> error: incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Context

```
adapter = new Adapter(models,this);
```

here is my **HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    //cardview
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Adapter adapter;
    List<Model> models;
    Integer[]colors = null;
    ArgbEvaluator argbEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        //cardview
        models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.brochure,"Brochure","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sticker,"Sticker","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
       models.add(new Model(R.drawable.poster,"Poster","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
       models.add(new Model(R.drawable.namecard,"Name Card","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));

        adapter = new Adapter(models,this);

        viewPager = getView().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPadding(130,0,130,0);
    }
}
```

Then here is my **Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<Model> models;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Model> models, Context context) {
        this.models = models;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,container,false);

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title,desc;

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc = view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        imageView.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage());
        title.setText(models.get(position).getTitle());
        desc.setText(models.get(position).getDesc());

        container.addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
adapter = new Adapter(models,this);
```

to this:

```
adapter = new Adapter(models, (Context) getActivity());
```

You've to pass `Context`. And a `Activity` is cast-able to `Context` but a `Fragment` is not.

So, you've to retrieve a instance of current `Activity`, which we are doing by `getActivity()`.

If you want to create instance of `Adapter` in a `Activity`, then you can do that by simple passing `this`, like I said before, a `Activity` is cast-able to `Context` but a `Fragment` is not. So `Activity` will be casted to `Context`, but when you want to create the same in a `Fragment` then you cannot simply pass `this`, thus, it raised an error.

As you said in comment, now there is another error, That is because you are already `return`ed something on the first line of that method, so, every line under that will never be reached, that is why there is that error, place this line

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
```

at the end and error will be gone.

After some more editing in your method, your `OnCreateView` will look something like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false); // Created a instance of View which we can return later.

    //cardview
    models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.brochure,"Brochure","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sticker,"Sticker","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.poster,"Poster","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.namecard,"Name Card","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));

    adapter = new Adapter(models,this);

    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager); // Change getView() to view here.
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPadding(130,0,130,0);

    return view; // Returned the view.
}
```

Comment: thanks, the error is gone, but there is a new error its say "error: unreachable statement" on "models = new ArrayList<>();"

Comment: Which line i have to delete ?

Comment: @user3291362 I've edited it, reload page and check my answer now

Comment: Dammmnn the error is gone man, thanks, youre superb :D, but why when i run this code, the application is force close, then i saw the log there is an error on "viewPager = getView().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);"

Comment: @user3291362, this error was there because `getView()` was returning `null` at this time, so there was a `NullPointerException` (*I guess*), but now we used an alternative option and got rid of `getView()`, So now no more `NullPointerException`s

Answer (score 1):

In place of `this`, use `getActivity()`

Change this

```
adapter = new Adapter(models,this);
```

to

```
adapter = new Adapter(models,getActivity());
```

Comment: thanks, the error is gone, but there is a new error its say "error: unreachable statement" on "models = new ArrayList<>();"